# Jekyll: DRY'ing up partials using same HTML structure

Tags: html, jekyll, dry

In my Jekyll site, each page includes a partial near the bottom. The text for each type of partial varies, but the HTML structure is the same. To illustrate...

Folder structure:

```
_includes
  - partial1.html
  - partial2.html
pages
  - page1.html
  - page2.html
  - page3.html
```

partial1.html

```
<div class="container">
  <h3>Buy now</h3>
  <p>It'll be the best decision you ever made.</p>
</div>
```

partial2.html

```
<div class="container">
  <h3>Sign up for our newsletter</h3>
  <p>We won't spam you (too much).</p>
</div>
```

page1.html

```
---
layout: default
title: Page 1
---

...

{% include partial1.html %}
```

page2.html

```
---
layout: default
title: Page 2
---

...

{% include partial2.html %}
```

page3.html

```
---
layout: default
title: Page 3
---

...

{% include partial2.html %}
```

Right now the partials just duplicate the HTML structure, but I'd prefer to inject a master template with the unique values. If you could use frontmatter in the includes folder, that would be one way to clean-up, but Jekyll doesn't support that.

What's the best way to approach this scenario?

(If my issue isn't clear, just let me know and I'll try to clarify through additional sample code.)

Comment: An example would be helpful to fully understand the problem.

Comment: Bit clearer now?

Comment: Yes, clearer, but I don't get much what would be the "master template" , you mean a solution to avoid repeating the structure in both partials?

Comment: Yes that's correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial texts can be in each partial or in a data file, so the html will be in another one:

## in each partial

A main `partial.html` holding the html structure:

```
<div class="container">
    <h3>{{include.h}}</h3>
    <p>{{include.p}}</p>
</div>
```

then each partial will call it using include variables:

- **partial1.html**:

  ```
  {% assign header = "Buy now" %}
  {% assign paragraph = "It'll be the best decision you ever made." %}
  {% include partial.html h=header p=paragraph%}
  ```
- **partial2.html**:

  ```
  {% assign header = "Sign up for our newsletter" %}
  {% assign paragraph = "We won't spam you (too much)." %}
  {% include partial.html h=header p=paragraph%}
  ```

## using a data file

- Create a file `_data/partial.yml` that will contain the text:

  ```
  buy:
      h: "Buy now"
      p: "It'll be the best decision you ever made."
  sign:
      h: "Sign up for our newsletter"
      p: "We won't spam you (too much)."
  ```

Then in each partial use the data:

- partial1.html:

  ```
   {% include partial.html type="buy"%}
  ```
- partial2.html:

  ```
   {% include partial.html type="sign" %}
  ```
- in each page: (ex: page1.html)

  ```
  ---
  layout: default
  title: Page 1
  ---

  ...

  {% include partial1.html %}
  ```